# Javascript wait for button press before resuming function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want the user to be able to choose whether they want the received ace card to be worth 1 or 11. I therefore prompt them with two buttons (#aceOne and #aceEleven) but I want to wait until they set the value themselves by pressing one before continuing the game.

The pressed buttons invoke the function aceWorth(ace)(This function also does other things) - passing the parameter 1 or 11 depending on button press, the function sets its value.

So - how do I force halt the code until the user presses one of the buttons - and then run the function (aceworth) to set the value of the card?

```
document.getElementById("aceOne").addEventListener("click", aceWorth(1))
document.getElementById("aceEleven").addEventListener("click", aceWorth(11))

function aceWorth(ace){
    window.cardValue = ace}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the below line while passing the return value of **aceWorth(1) as parmeter** instead of the function is not how you can bind events.

You are calling aceWorth() and binding it's return value as argument. Try to use the arrow Syntax `() => {doSomething();}`

```
.addEventListener("click", aceWorth(1))
```

---

You can do something like this:

```js
function aceWorth(ace) {
    window.cardValue = ace;
    console.log(ace);
}
    
aceOne.addEventListener("click", () => aceWorth(1));
aceEleven.addEventListener("click", () => aceWorth(11));
```

```html
<button id="aceOne">1</button>
<button id="aceEleven">11</button>
```